# Python will run in Unix, not Windows. How can you run an external python command in terminal?

Tags: python, windows, shell, ipython, windows-shell

I am trying to run some code in iPython which

```
will read in a tsv as a list,
go through it row-by row, 
    run an external python command on each line, 
    save the output into a list
append this to our tsv at the end.
```

My code runs in a Unix environment, but I cannot make it run using iPython and Windows. The external function that I call will also work when called in a windows terminal, but not when called, as below, in an iPython notebook. What have I done wrong? What else can I try?

Here is my code :

```
import csv
import GetAlexRanking #External Method exposed here
import subprocess
import pandas as p
loadData = lambda f: np.genfromtxt(open(f,'r'), delimiter=' ')
with open('list.tsv','rb') as tsvin, open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvout:
    tsvin = csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter='\t')
    csvout = csv.writer(csvout)

    for row in tsvin:
        count = 0
        url = str([row[count]])
        cmd = subprocess.Popen("python GetAlexRanking.py " + url ,shell=True)
        cmd_out, cmd_err = cmd.communicate()
        cmd_string = str(cmd_out)
        print ">>>>>>>URL : " + url + " " + cmd_string #testing
        csvout.writerows(url + "\t" + cmd_string) #writing
        count+=1
```

How can I make this code run using iPython in Windows? It currently gives no error but the cmd_out variable always prints "None" rather than a correct value - the python command isn't being run correctly (however it will work in a normal Python/Unix environment).

Edit: Also runs correctly when ran from Windows terminal.

Comment: you may need to fire up the debugger

Comment: You're not escaping `url`, so that could cause all sorts of trouble. Pass the arguments as a list like: `['python', 'script', url]` to make `Popen` do the escaping for you. The `python` binary may also not be in your `%PATH%`, so try using a full path (ie. `C:/python33/python.exe`), or set the `%PATH%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "GetAlexRanking.py", url])
```

and better pass `os.abspath("GetAlexRanking.py")` as argument.

```
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe'
```

can be used on Windows, Linux, Mac.